# VMWare vSphere packet loss

Tags: linux, networking, vmware-esxi, packetloss

I have a Dell Blade Enclosure with 14 blades and ESXi 5.5 on it. On blade 7 and 14 I have round about 65 % packet loss when I ping the ESXi Management interface. On all other blades there ist no packet loss.
The strange thing is, I have this packet loss when I ping from:

blade 1 to blade 7 = 65% packet loss

but, when I ping from blade 7 to blade 1 at the same time I ping from blade 1 to blade 7 I have no packet loss at all ... not from 1 to 7 norr from 7 to 1

blade 1 to blade 7 and blade 7 to blade 1 = 0% packet loss

I have increased the Rx buffer in the ESX CLI but it doesn´t help.
When I do a esxtop and go to the networktab I don´t see any packetdrop

`PORT-ID     USED-BY   TEAM-PNIC   DNAME    PKTTX/s  MbTX/s  PKTRX/s MbRX/s  %DRPTX  %DRPRX
33554433    Management  n/a       vSwitch0  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
33554434    vmnic0       -        vSwitch0  22.73   0.04    44.50   0.10    0.00    0.00
33554435    Shadow of vmnic0 n/a  vSwitch0  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
33554436    vmnic1       -        vSwitch0  43.39   0.08    1.91    0.00    0.00    0.00
33554437    Shadow of vmnic1 n/a  vSwitch0  0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
33554438    vmk0       all(2)     vSwitch0  3.66    0.01    1.91    0.00    0.00    0.00`

The only thing I see that there are massive interrupts for 0xef:

`VECTOR  COUNT/s TIME/int COUNT_0 COUNT_1 COUNT_2 COUNT_3 COUNT_4 COUNT...
0xef    4435.5  1.0      309.2   275.6   402.9   30.5    339.0   15.3 ...`

The switch logfile shows me, that the blade network card is flapping sometimes, when I say sometimes I mean once or twice a week for about 1 or 2 minutes.

I don´t think that`s the reason for that but I haven´t any idea anymore what can be the problem. Especially the ping and counter ping situation don´t make any sense to me.
Maybe you can help me?

Comment: What kind of networking have you at the back of the blade enclosure?

Comment: behind the blade enclosure I have a Dell PowerConnect M6348. I already checked the error counters but they are all on 0. I try also to ping from the switch to the Management Network (vmnic0). I also have the same packetloss...

Comment: Speed/Duplex mismatch?

Comment: The switch port and the ESXi have both speed 1000 and Full-duplex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem and a solution.

The packet loss was caused by identical MAC-addresses on different switch ports.

The virtual interface VMK0 Blade 7 had the same MAC as the hardware interface of Blade 11.

So what I've done is this: I gave the VMK0 interface a new MAC address. 
For that I go over the iDRAC interface of the Blade Enclosure and loging into the ESXi "GUI". I removed my both networkcards from the Administration interface, restart the Management Network, added them and restart the Management Network again. So I had some downtime but after that the MAC address was changed and there was no packet loss anymore.

Comment: How did this even happen???

Comment: I have no idea how this could happen .... It just happened ...

Comment: Obscure. But can you post the build numbers of your ESXi 5.5 hosts?

Comment: On Blade 7 ESXi 5.5.0 Build 2068190
On Blade 11 I didn´t have any ESXi on it.